# Browser keeps refreshing tabs

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, browser

I have a LG V480 (1GB RAM; LG Lollipop 5.0.2), when switching from one tab to another tab which was loaded before, it will reload it.

Example: 3 tabs with 3 websites, everytime i switch tab it will reload the tab i switch to.
Video..
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WjEGnTxsj3c

Its very annoying, if i had written this question on the tablet and for some reason i clicked in another tab, when returning to the question, i had to write all over again! Its not multitasked, its time/bandwidth wasting. Also tried to set to default the tablet, but the issue remains.

Tried with Chrome (preferred one), Firefox, Opera, some others browsers, and all behaves like this, some better, other worse.

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: It's probably the LMK (low-memory killer) that kills suspended threads for tabs that are not visible. They then need to be restarted and all of their data needs to be reloaded again.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I did a follow up on your answer and Mikhail in his answer..

Comment: Its probaly in the websites code to refresh to keep you up to date with the websites content.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely those tabs are just getting killed. Remember that in Chrome, page renderers run in separate processes for security. Once a renderer process has been put into background, the system is free to kill it. According to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=98332, the issue with over-aggressive process killing should be resolved in the 5.1 update. Hopefully, LG will release this update for V480 soon.

Comment: Thanks for the answer..that makes sense.5.0.2 was released for this model some days after i purchased the tablet, originally was 4.4.2..do you think 4.4.2 also suffers this issue? I´m thinking on downgrading, if solves the issue..

Comment: I think 4.4.2 is actually better than 5.0 for non hi-end devices. For KitKat there had been a special effort in order to minimize memory usage (see http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/10/31/kitkat-feature-spotlight-project-svelte-extends-android-4-4-support-to-devices-with-as-little-as-512mb-of-ram/). Then in the initial release of Lollipop, things got bad again. This was fixed in 5.1. So until it becomes available for your device, it is wiser to keep with KitKat.